# Custom OSK: Listen to TextBox Focus

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have written a custom OnScreen Keyboard as an UserControl to have a better control over what the user can type (Alphanumeric/Numpad/Navigation Keys - stuff like that) and to have a better control over the screen layout at design time.

The OSK works by manipulating the text- and selection-properties/functions of a textbox-control.

**My main Problem is how to find the right TextBox to inject text into.**

My first, naive approach was to register every TextBox I want to use with the OSK Control manually and use the GotFocus/LostFocus of those registered TextBoxes to determine the active control:

```
public void RegisterInput(TextBox text) {
    if (!_listeners.ContainsKey(text)) {
        _listeners.Add(text, modes);
        text.GotFocus += Input_OnGotFocus;
        text.LostFocus += Input_OnLostFocus;
    }
}

private void Input_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
    if (_focused == sender) {
        _focused = null;
        IsEnabled = false;            
        UpdateKeyboardMode(); // << Updates Keyboard layout (Alphanumerical vs Numpad) based on focused control
    }
}

private void Input_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
    _focused = (TextBox) sender;
    IsEnabled = true;        
    UpdateKeyboardMode();
    Bindings.Update();
}
```

I work with Focus here, because I need to determine which kind of keyboard (full-size alphanumerical vs. short numpad) to display for each TextBox. The `_focused` TextBox is then used to directly inject the pressed keys into it. In the constructor of my Page which also contains the OSK-control I would call `RegisterInput()` with a reference of each and every TextBox I defined on the page. This works just fine — if I have those references.

But now I am working with UserControls. That also removes the TextBoxes out of reach for direct referencing, but I could write some kind of VisualTree-Scan after `InitializeComponent()` to find all references and call `RegisterInput()` on each reference I found. If I only need to do this once, it isn't a problem (altough it is still ugly).

One step further - ListBoxes with dynamicly changing contents and DataTemplates. Now I'd need to rescan the whole VisualTree explicitly everytime something changes. But how to detect those changes?

**The question is:** Can I get an event as soon as $any element in my VisualTree gets/looses focus, without knowing all those elements beforehand (thus replacing `RegisterInput()` completely)? Or can I listen to changes to the VisualTree to rescan all controls and then call `RegisterInput()` manually for every TextBox I found?

The goal is to get a handler called everytime a GetFocus/LostFocus event on any TextBox/Control in the UI is raised so that I can update the keyboard to either display a full-sized alphanumerical keyboard (for default textboxes) or a shortened numpad (e.g. for textboxes bound to numerical backing fields).

**Alternatively:** Is there any other way to inject text **and** call `UpdateKeyboardMode()` to update the keyboard layout as soon as the selected textbox changes?

**Other options I thought about include:**

1. Build a custom control which derives from a TextBox and let it register itself to the OSK. I'll probably resort to this method, if I don't find any better way. But this will destroy support for 3rd party libraries in which my control is not present and thus does not use the "special magical textbox with osk support".
2. Don't use events at all. Get the currently focused TextBox with the FocusManager as soon as the user presses a key on my OSK and inject text into the focused instance. Problem with this approach is, that it completely destroys the capability to adapt the OSK to different input types (alphanumerical vs only Numpad), because I cannot determine the keyboard type I need before pressing a key.
3. Rescan the VisualTree with a timer. Won't do that, thats simply too much of a hack.
4. Use the OnScreen-Keyboard supplied by Win10 IoT. Two problems: It has no designtime support and is displayed above elements, even if the focused element is directly underneath the keyboard (acceptable if neccessary), but I don't know of a way to change the keyboard "layout" between a full-sized alphanumeric keyboard and a shortened Numpad which only contains numbers and some keys. Also it does not allow to use custom keys (e.g. arrow keys for navigation, custom return key handling).

Comment: That is part of the problem, yes. I'll try to be more clearly about the actual things in the quesiton.

Comment: The link does not work, because I'm using a hand-made control. I'm using a hand-made control to have -> more control over layouting my page while in design mode (the osk of win10 iot does not work that good because it obstructs UI elements) -> and to have the decision whether I want to display a full sized alphanumeric keyboard or a shortened numpad. Question updated.

Comment: Types of keyboards: I would like to have two layouts: one full sized alphanumeric layout or a shorter numpad-only layout. This allows me to better adapt for numeric-input-only textboxes and general purpose all-characters-allowed textboxes.

Comment: While that works, I think Option 1 is pretty close to this idea (basically the same but without an embedded osk). And has the same drawbacks - no 3rd party support.

Comment: If I use a custom control from another library this control won't have support for my OSK. Also it is a lot harder to fix all the layouting issues that will arise from a control that changes it's size so drastically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165375/discussion-between-iam-carrot-and-cshark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion in the chat forum, the actual problem isn't to create a `Custom OSK` control and use that to interact with the `TextBoxs` but instead, it's "being bound to use custom control" wrapping a `textbox` everywhere a `OSK` needs to be shown.

The Solution would be to listen to the OS-OSK events and when they are triggered, pop up the `Custom OSK` this ways you won't have to wrap a `Textbox` in a user control and use that throughout your project.

Link to the Documentation: -  [respond to the presence of the touch keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/respond-to-the-presence-of-the-touch-keyboard)

Comment: Hm. Either I'm stupid or win10 iot does not work that way. i cannot manipulate the OS-OSK in any way following the docs. I don't even get the events for showing/hiding the OSK and accessing the properties of the InputPane throws exceptions (InvalidCast). No manual hiding/showing possible. Also InputScope (to manipulate the keyboard layout) does not work at all. But outside of win10 iot a solid answer!

Comment: Accepting because it /should/ work but doesn't because of an os bug.